# Trained a text-classification model and want to pass a .csv file with text items to predict

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl, google-cloud-nl, google-cloud-automl-nl

I have already trained my data set in Google auto ml. Now I want to pass a CSV with text items to predict its labels. Not sure on how to proceed

Have passed 17k text items with labels.

Have seen rest API & python codes to execute.

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=key-file-path
curl -X POST \ -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)" \ -H "Content-Type: application/json" \ https://automl.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/ticket-classification-poc/locations/us-central1/models/TCN8669499774734365168:predict \ -d '{ "payload" : { "textSnippet": { "content": "YOUR TEXT HERE", "mime_type": "text/plain" }, } }' Output : Need to pass future text items in bulk for prediction
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a loop to go through all the CSV items programatically and send one by one.